# jQuery variable assignment confusion

Tags: javascript, jquery

I just ran into a [jQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery) code example which confuses me a bit.

```
var $tasks = $('#task_list'), i;
```

This was used to get the **ul element** from the [DOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) and store it in the `$tasks` variable.

But why the **`i`** at the end?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is exactly the same as:

```
var $tasks = $('#task_list');
var i;
```

It’s just a different syntax using commas between `var` statements.

You can read more about the `var` statement and peek at more advanced examples here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var

Comment: +1. Side note: most minimized JavaScript code looks this way as it saves several characters for the same result.

Comment: Plus its cleaner to put them out on one stmt at the start since JS anyway only has function level scope.

Comment: excellent.  thanks, i've been bustin my small brain trying to figure this out.